# Unknown (Graphics) Pleasure

Tags: plotting, graphics, generative-art

I want to make a program that produces images like this one

[image]

What I have tried...

```
ListLinePlot[
Table[Join[Table[2 RandomReal[], 15], 
Accumulate[RandomChoice[Range[-20, 20], 20]], 
Table[2 RandomReal[], 15]] + k, {k, 1, 300, 10}], 
PlotStyle -> 
Directive[RGBColor[1., 1., 1.], Opacity[1.], 
AbsoluteThickness[1.015]], Axes -> False, Background -> Black]
```

this code returns random images like the following

[image]

as you can see every line must cover the line(s) above it.
I tried Filling and FillingStyle but I can't make it work.
How can I accomplish this?

You don't have to use my code.
Make your own if it is easier for you..

Comment: http://intothecontinuum.tumblr.com/post/27443100682/in-july-1967-astronomers-at-the-cavendish

Comment: nice! but I think that it would be better without Sin curves. Any ideas on how to make something very similar to the first pic I posted?

Comment: Search for "pulsar" and few related topic will appear.

Comment: @Kuba I don't have a problem making a pulsar like img. My problem which is about plotting in Mathematica is how to make the upper lines disappear. It has nothing to do with pulsars or if you like joy division..

Comment: I didn't mean google but se. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=pulsar

Comment: @Kuba I didn't mean google either... My question is very specific. How the lower curves "hide" the upper ones. Please take a look at both pics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that the lines are shown through the axis filling if you plot all the data series in one plot. The solution to that is to plot them separately and then combine them using `Show`. The second problem is that we have to plot the upper ones before the lower ones since the lower ones are supposed to overlap the upper ones and not vice-versa. For that I used `{k, 300, 1, -10}` instead of `{k, 1, 300, 10}`. The code now looks like this:

```
data = Table[
   Join[Table[2 RandomReal[], 15], 
     Accumulate[RandomChoice[Range[-20, 20], 20]], 
     Table[2 RandomReal[], 15]] + k, {k, 300, 1, -10}];

Show[ListLinePlot[
    #,
    PlotStyle -> 
     Directive[RGBColor[1., 1., 1.], Opacity[1.], 
      AbsoluteThickness[1.015]],
    Axes -> False,
    Background -> Black,
    Filling -> Axis,
    FillingStyle -> Black,
    PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {0, 400}}
    ] & /@ data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And if you're wondering how I found the plot range, I simply plotted all the data in one plot first and took notice of what the plot range seemed to be and wrote that down.

Comment: this is very nice. thank you

Comment: PlotRange -> {{-20, 70}, {-70, 400}}   gives a better result ;-)

Answer (score 7):

We've lost control... again

[image]

```
Transpose@Table[{x, y + 3 Exp[-((x - Sin[y/5])/3)^2] (.5 + RandomReal[{-.2, 1}])}, {x, -8, 8, .5}, {y, 0, 50}] // Short
Show[ListPlot[#, Joined -> True, Filling -> Bottom, FillingStyle -> Black, PlotStyle -> {Thin, White}, Background -> Black, PlotRange -> {{-15, 15}, {-10, 60}}, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> Large] & /@ Reverse@%, AspectRatio -> 1]
```